# Keep Computer Modern as bold font

Tags: xetex

I want to use Gentium as my mainfont and that is done by the command \usepackage{Gentium}. But I want "Computer Modern" to be my Bold font. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why would you want to commit such a sin in this time of the year? ;-) Out of joke, can you tell a reason for your wish?

Comment: `Fontspec` can probably do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `Gentium` package, but `gentium`; using uppercase in the package name can work in case insensitive file systems (Windows), but limits file portability, as `\usepackage{Gentium}` won't work on GNU/Linux or Mac OS X systems.

A simplistic solution is by patching `\bfseries` and `\mdseries` to check the current font family and, if it is the default (`gentium`), switch to CM, for `\bfseries`; to the contrary, if the font family is CM, switch to `gentium`.

Other font families are not affected as shown in the example.

However, the example also shows that Computer Moder Roman Bold is visually incompatible with Gentium, so I strongly advise you not to do this. Adventor and Cursor are used here just by way of example and I make no claim they're to be used along with Gentium.

As a general typographic rule, a normal document should use just one serif font family.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gentium}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\usepackage{xpatch,pdftexcmds}

\xpatchcmd{\bfseries}
  {\selectfont}
  {\checkfamily{\familydefault}{cmr}\selectfont}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mdseries}
  {\selectfont}
  {\checkfamily{cmr}{\familydefault}\selectfont}
  {}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checkfamily}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@family}{#1}=\z@
    \fontfamily{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text in Gentium and \textbf{some in CM {\mdseries (this is Gentium)} and back to CM}

\sffamily
Some text in Adventor and \textbf{some in bf {\mdseries (this is md)} and back to bf}

\ttfamily
Some text in Cursor and \textbf{some in bf {\mdseries (this is md)} and back to bf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A magnified view better showing the font clash

[image]

A longer and possibly more robust solution involves modifying the `.fd` files for Gentium.

If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then you can get this more easily:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Gentium}[
  BoldFont={Latin Modern Roman 10 Bold}
]
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
```

Some more juggling with the sizes should be necessary.