# Two different "main fonts" in use; use only one for numbers

Tags: xetex, fontspec, italic

I have defined a `mainfont`, but have further defined its italics to come from a different font. **My question:** What is the simplest way to get the "original" main font back **just for numbers**?

I wish to set up my document with a good serif font with old style numbers. But I also need that font to have [well-behaved stacking diacritics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294998/46980) for italics. Finding that apparently simple combination is proving quite difficult: my preferred fonts with old-style numbers misbehave with diacritics; the best behaved fonts for diacritics lack old-style numbers.

So I have come up with this dodge:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
    ItalicFont=Gentium Plus Italic,
    Numbers=OldStyle
]

\begin{document}

In 2013 it \textit{looks} new, but in \textit{2019} it won't.

\end{document}
```

But it leads to this result:

[image: result]

I will only rarely need to use italics where numbers are involved. Thus my question: what is the simplest way of pulling the *italics* old-style numbers from (in this case) TeX Gyre Pagella (the "original" main font), rather than from Gentium Plus (the italics partner)? (I have looked at [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/46980) or [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219181/46980) other Q&As, but the discussions I have found don't quite address this specific issue.)

---

*Update* - I haven't been able to crack this one with my neophyte knowledge of TeX. I have now run across these Q&As which either pose a related problem, or suggest a possible approach:

- [Mix characters from various fonts (in text mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204761/)
- [How to mix accents from different fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/) (see queries appended in comments)
- [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/)
- [Taking letters and numbers from different fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139548/) (it's not clear to me how this is a duplicate of the above)

Along with a couple of commentators to this question, I'm still interested in whether any flavour of TeX can solve this general problem, and if so ... how!

Comment: I installed Gentium Plus, but it doesn't appear to have old style numerals.

Comment: Thanks for checking, egreg - but that's my point! I think I see another possibility though. Perhaps I need to say more about my "use case". About to post a "selfie". :)

Comment: I would be interested in a more general answer to that question too, if anyone has the skill to produce it (if even possible without too much hassle). I have a font which is just perfect for everything *except* numbers and for which I would like a substitute.

Comment: @ienissei I too would be interested in a more general answer.  Even in OpenType, some typefaces have their old style figures in a separate, small caps font (e.g., Schneidler, from URW++).  It would be desirable not to have to surround all numbers with `\textsc{}` in the source.

Answer (score 1):

For my immediate needs, the following "solution" suffices.

Since the "well-behaved diacritics" are only needed for "scientific" transliterations, is there any reason why I shouldn't use this **work-around**:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\newfontfamily{\Tr}{Gentium Plus Italic}

\begin{document}

In 2013 it \textit{looks} new, but in \textit{2019} it won't.

Using `italics' gives me \textit{hå̄ʾå̄rɛṣ}, but using the \texttt{Tr} `font family', with well-behaved diacritics, I get {\Tr hå̄ʾå̄rɛṣ}.

TeXGP \textit{italics} but GenPlus {\Tr italics}.

\end{document}
```

This allows for "mainfont" italics (which include old-style numbers) for general "italics" use, but the "well-behaved" font for transliterations. Here's the new result:

[image: new result]

Comment: The two italics are to similar to my liking. One can see that they are different, but it is not enough to show that it is by purpose.